# NSTimer going very fast in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, nstimer

I am using `NSTimer` for making a stop watch. I have used three buttons for *play*, *pause* and *stop*. All three are working fine. But when I am clicking on *play* button more than once it starts counting fast. After that *pause* and *stop* button are not working. I understand that by clicking play more than once, I am starting many timers but the thing I am not getting is that why pause and stop not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make timer object global for that class.

Before play check timer check `isValid` like so `if(timer.isValid== false)` then start timer else do nothing. Regarding to *stop* and *pause* also if timer *isValid* then stop or pause it .

Comment: Thanks for your answer ios learner. But this is the solution for it. i want to know why we are not able to stop the timer. why timer.invalidate() is not working?

Comment: i think you are creating new object for timer every time and when you create   new object old object will running and you lost old timer reference  and when you are trying invalidate only newly created will invalid and the old one is running but you lost its reference  so you can not invalidate it

Comment: timer object is global. see the code for the play button    @IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        
    //    if check{
             // check=false
                timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:Selector("incrementor") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

Comment: i mean when you call scheduledTimer check timer is valid or not because if you call multiple time scheduledTimer on start click then there are so many reference for timer created put condition like below 
 `if (!timer.isValid){
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(progressTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];}`

Comment: ohk i got what you are saying. So the thing is that there are many references for timer and invalidate() function is only able to invalidate only the recent reference of the timer. Thanks a lot ios learner. :)